# NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory on Jenkins with gradle

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle

I am trying to prepare a basic pipeline on jenkins, and although the local build works ok for the same task, it fails on jenkins with

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.CompositeStoppable.<clinit>(CompositeStoppable.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.tryClose(ClassLoaderUtils.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

The build file has the below configs for dependencies:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module:'guava-jdk5'
    all*.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-core'
    all*.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
    all*.exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.0'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.29'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-log4j12', version:'1.5.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.10.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.10.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.10.0'
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:23.0"
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.7'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '5.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.1-groovy-2.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-spring', version: '1.1-groovy-2.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    testCompile "cglib:cglib:2.2"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

jenkins file

```
    pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
  stage("Build") {
    steps {
      bat 'project/gradlew.bat -Djava.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_172 -b project/build.gradle test'
      }
  }
 }
}
```

I have tried to update the versions of the libs and enabled/disabled the exclusion parts, but the error still happens on jenkins, while on my local nothing unusual. can anyone point out what might be the reason and solution to that?

Comment: look at jenkins console output and find the command that it tries to run. It seems the war file does not contain jar libraries.

Comment: would adding the dependencies to the classpath with the jenkinsfile help? or it has to be the jenkins war file?

Comment: one thing i realised was the path delim... the machine is a windows machine, so forward slashes was breaking the cli tool. I have fixed that part, but the error still doesnt make sense for the cli parsing, as it shows completely different stacktrace